# Angular Material

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design, angular-material

So i have installed angular, angular-material, angular-aria, angular-animate dependencies to my system.
I just want to test out this up and coming styling method.
It seems I'm stuck at the beginning. Can you tell me whats wrong with the code?

These are my 3 files.

1. app.js
2. styles.css
3. index.html

My output is **{{title1}}** at the centre-top of the webpage.

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.title1 = 'Lol';
  });
```

```css
.buttondemoBasicUsage section {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
  position: relative !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.buttondemoBasicUsage md-content {
  margin-right: 7px;
}
.buttondemoBasicUsage section .md-button {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="angular-material.css">
  <title>AngularJS</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <md-content>
      <section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center">
        <md-button>{{title1}}</md-button>
      </section>
    </md-content>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I fixed your imports (see my edit) and it's working.

Comment: I do not see any edits. :O

Comment: Hmm ok.Look to my answer

Answer (score 2):

This is really just a matter of referencing the files to the correct places in your project.

Replacing all your local references to CDN's, your code is working flawlessly: http://codepen.io/qvazzler/pen/vOaqXW

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.10.0/angular-material.css">
    <title>AngularJS</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <md-content>
            <section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center">
                <md-button>{{title1}}</md-button>
            </section>
        </md-content>
    </div>
<!--    <script src="MyApp.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.10.0/angular-material.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

A helpful thing to do in these cases is to open the Chrome developer tools (CTRL + SHIFT + I), get to the Console section and look at the error messages.

Link to guide on using DevTools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

If I were to actually answer your question on why it's not working, we'd have to see your file structure, but as it is common that js files are located in a folder separate from your html files, you'd have to add "../" to the beginning of your href's to access a parent folder.

Example:

```
[My Project]
jsfolder
- angular.js
- angular-material.js
cssfolder
- angular-material.css
- styles.css
html
- index.html
```

To access angular.js from your index.html, you'd have to write **href="../jsfolder/angular.js"**

Comment: Thanks all. Turns out i had to import my dependencies first and then my .js and .css file.

Comment: @VarunVerma , do let me know, is there anything in my answer that was not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your imports.

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.title1 = 'Lol';
  });
```

```css
.buttondemoBasicUsage section {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
  position: relative !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.buttondemoBasicUsage md-content {
  margin-right: 7px;
}
.buttondemoBasicUsage section .md-button {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="angular-material.css">
  <title>AngularJS</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <md-content>
      <section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center">
        <md-button>{{title1}}</md-button>
      </section>
    </md-content>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay i found it. Sorry for that. When i run the code snippet here on sof, it works but when i copy paste the same to my files, it still shows me the same result, both on chrome and IE8

Comment: @Christoph, you forgot to change the angular-material.css to a CDN-hosted location. Then again, this answer does not truly reflect on why Varun cannot reference his files.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use typescripts or a kind of that option, first steps are hard but later you ll be in better solution.

please dont make writing code pain and gain.

happy codings.